# want to read specific line by giving my own range

Tags: php

I've been preparing a code for finding some specific lines from text file by giving my range of lines

```
$file         = new SplFileObject("TRIAL.txt");
$fileIterator = new LimitIterator($file, "40-01-0001", "40-01-0010");

foreach($fileIterator as $line) {
  echo $line, PHP_EOL;
  echo "<br>";
}
```

I'm giving this code. Please someone show me the fault in this code. In this code, `"40-01-0001"`, `"40-01-0050"` are starting of `X` line to `Y` line. And I need to read all lines between the `X` line to `Y` line.

Comment: Is `40-01-0001` a line number?

Comment: its line name, as I want to search this line.

Comment: A line has a name? how do you store it?

Comment: let me explain
40-01-0001 is an id of a person and starting of line
and I want to read the detail of this id, which is written on one line.

Comment: Are you trying to read any csv/tsv type data?

Comment: I wish it may be!!!
it is seen in csv such type of file but its in txt file with some text details. Thatswhy it is creating problem.

Comment: Could you show first 5-7 lines of the file?

Comment: 40-01-0001 John                     560,392.94             0.21
40-01-0002 Hameed                   2,591,968.53           0.00
40-01-0031 Cheem                    0.50                   0.00
40-01-0032                          0.00                   5,702.93
these are in list form

Comment: These are separated by ` ` character. You better use `fgetcsv` and `fopen` here. Using array_filter you can search between them too.

Answer (score 0):

[`LimitIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php) takes 3 arguments in constructor:

```
public __construct( Iterator $iterator [, int $offset = 0 [, int $count = -1 ]] )
```

So it cannot be string value - just an integer index.

Answer (score 0):

Use [splFileObject::seek](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.seek.php)

```
$file = new SplFileObject('TRIAL.txt');
$file->seek(LINE_NUMBER);
```